# Removing 'index.php?' with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working on Wamp with PHP 5.3.5 with `htaccess` extesnion enabled.

The problem I am facing is that I need something like this `http://localhost/abc/aboutus`.

Now the actual URL is something like this `http://localhost/abc/index.php?aboutus`

I tried the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And try using it like `http://localhost/abc/aboutus` but it doesn't work for. But when I try it like `http://localhost/abc/?aboutus`.

It works fine but I actually want to remove the `?` from URL. Can anyone tell me where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to account for the `/abc/` URI base in your rules. So if the htaccess file is in your document root, the rules need to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)$ /abc/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But if the rules are in an htaccess file that is *in the **/abc/** folder*, then they need to look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I think you need a slash in front of the pattern `^/abc/(.*)$` and remove the slash in the query string `...?$1`.

Comment: @OlafDietsche You only need a slash in front of the pattern if the rules are in server or vhost config. The slash is always stripped from the URI before being sent to rules in an htaccess file

Comment: Hi, Thanks Jon Lin for your reply i worked on the this and it worked somehow but once i uploaded it to server on the main root folder.
Here is what i am exactly want to know from you "http://www.webmekanics.com/index.php?about"
this doesn't work what i have to do for this over server with your same rewriting rules. 
http://www.webmekanics.com/?about i need always to put ? to access any page which i don't want to show on removing ? it redirects me back to home page.
Regards